# How to loop through objects within a div class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now, and it's been really frustrating me. I'm writing what I thought should be an easy infinite image swap within a div, then calling that particular div a class so I can use it multiple times on the same page. Here is the code I'm using below:

HTML:

```html
<div class="project">
<div class="project_images">
  <img src="../images/portfolio/placeholder.jpg" />
  <img src="../images/portfolio/placeholder2.jpg" />
  <img src="../images/portfolio/placeholder3.jpg" />
  <img src="../images/portfolio/placeholder4.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="project_buttons">
  <a href="#" class="prev">PREV</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="project">
<div class="project_images">
  <img src="../images/portfolio/placeholder.jpg" />
  <img src="../images/portfolio/placeholder2.jpg" />
  <img src="../images/portfolio/placeholder3.jpg" />
  <img src="../images/portfolio/placeholder4.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="project_buttons">
  <a href="#" class="prev">PREV</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  next = function(){
    var thisFirst = $(this).parents('div').prev('.project_images img:first');
    var thisLast = $(this).parents('div').prev('.project_images img:last');

    thisLast.after(thisFirst);
  }

  prev = function(){
    var thisFirst = $(this).parent('div').prev('.project_images img:first');
    var thisLast = $(this).parent('div').prev('.project_images img:last');

    thisFirst.before(thisLast);
  }

  $('.prev').click(function(){
    prev();
  });

  $('.next').click(function(){
    next();
  });
});
```

When clicking the "NEXT" button within the first div class, images will drop into the second div class of the same name ("project_images"). I understand why it is doing this (`:first` and `:last` selectors), but I can't figure out a better way to select the objects and/or select only one instance of the "project_images" class.
Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  next = function(){
    var thisFirst = $(this).parents('.project').find('.project_images img:first');
    var thisLast = $(this).parents('.project').find('.project_images img:last');

    thisLast.after(thisFirst);
  }

  prev = function(){
    var thisFirst = $(this).parents('.project').find('.project_images img:first');
    var thisLast = $(this).parents('.project').find('.project_images img:last');

    thisFirst.before(thisLast);
  }

  $('.prev').click(prev);

  $('.next').click(next);
});
```

Comment: You also need to move the function into the click event, or $(this) is a empty value.

Comment: This, coupled with moving the function into the click event worked. Thanks!